# Cypress inserting "node_module" in search path

Tags: angular, cypress

I recently installed Cypress for running tests in my angular application, but whenever I try to run a test that has a import, I face this error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./src/main/webapp/app/shared/util/mesh-math.util.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app/shared/model/enumerations/method-inrush.model' in 'C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\app\shared\util'
resolve 'app/shared/model/enumerations/method-inrush.model' in 'C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\app\shared\util'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/util)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\app\shared\util\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\app\shared\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\app\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\webapp\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\main\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\src\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\node_modules]
[C:\node_modules]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.js]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.json]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.jsx]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.mjs]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.coffee]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.ts]
[C:\Projetos Headot\mesh\node_modules\app\shared\model\enumerations\method-inrush.model.tsx]
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/util/mesh-math.util.ts 27:28-88
 @ ./src/test/javascript/spec/app/shared/util/mesh-math.util.spec.ts
 
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:180:23)
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:98:28)
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:54:20
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:33
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.5.2\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```

And my tsconfig.base.json file, which holds the "paths":

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "build/resources/main/static/app",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": ["src/main/webapp/app/*"]
    },
    "importHelpers": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true
  }
}
```

cypress.json also has minimal configuration, only holding the tests location:

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "src/test/javascript/spec/app"
}
```

It seems that the problem is that, somehow, "node_modules" has been added to the path when looking for the files. I have no idea why it's doing that, though, nor do I know how to stop it.

In case it helps, these are the imports inside the mesh-math file:

```
import { MethodInrush } from 'app/shared/model/enumerations/method-inrush.model';
import { Transformer } from 'app/shared/model/transformer.model';
import { Impedancia } from 'app/shared/model/impedancia.model';
import Complex from 'complex-js';
import { DealershipSetting } from 'app/shared/model/dealership-setting.model';
```

And this is the simple test I'm trying to run:

```
import {MeshMathUtil} from "../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/util/mesh-math.util";

describe('Mesh Math Util', () => {
  it('should fail', () => {
    expect(MeshMathUtil.isZero(3)).toBeFalsy();
  })
})
```